# Getting error in Event Registration for Arguments

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating a project where I using Event registration for calling methods between `MainForm` and multiple `UserControl`(s) where every method is working fine. But, when I create event to close `MainForm` by using a `Close` button at the `UserControl` using event registration then I am getting error (Overloading and invalid arguments etc.). I tried to arguments (sender, e) but it does not work.

MainForm Code:

```
private void Open_ucGateEntry(object o1, object o2)
{
    pnlReplace.Controls.Clear();
    ucGateEnrty objucGateEnrty = new ucGateEnrty();
    pnlReplace.Controls.Add(objucGateEnrty);
    this.Text = "GRN Creation";
    objucGateEnrty.callBackEvent += new EventHandler(Open_ucGateEntryDetail);
    objucGateEnrty.frmClose += new EventHandler(Form1_FormClosed);  //Error is here

}

private void Open_ucGateEntryDetail(object o1, object o2)
{
    pnlReplace.Controls.Clear();
    ucGateEntryDetail objucGateEnrtyDetails = new ucGateEntryDetail();
    pnlReplace.Controls.Add(objucGateEnrtyDetails);
    this.Text = "GRN Creation Detail (Log Data)";
    objucGateEnrtyDetails.callBackEvent += new EventHandler(Open_ucGateEntry);
}

private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
     //some code and close
}
```

UserControl is this:

```
private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmClose(this, e);
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your `frmClose()` function?

Comment: @Theo see the last line of Open_ucGateEntry() mothod where the error is coming. It is event registration (public EventHandler) like the callBackEvent(). So that is all I have give here